# $watch a vue-router change on Vue app instance programmatically outside Vue instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I have a small package that was built in Vue2 that I'm trying to migrate to Vue3 now where a route is being watched programmatically by obtaining the App instance within vue-router and it's being watched like so:

```
function myPluginName(router) {
  router.app.$watch(`$route.query.${this.config.name}`, () => {
   // do stuff outside my vue instance
  });
}
```

And its being called within my Vue component like so:

```
myPluginName(this.$router);
```

In my Main JS I added the router to my Vue instance:

```
const app = createApp(App);
router.app = app;
app.use(router);
```

Which works fine and I can get the `router.app` as an instance.
However in Vue2 you could add a `$watch` to your app instance and it would catch it for you; this doesn't seem to be the case with Vue3 since `console.log`ging my Vue instance doesn't show any sign of `$watch` nor does it work.

**So in short:**

Is there still a way I can watch my Vue instance OUTSIDE my Vue instance?

**Update:**

It does work when I push my Vue instance into the router.app in my component:

```
this.$router.app = this
myPluginName(this.$router);
```

But that doesn't feel really fool-proof ish I guess?

Comment: Can't you just import `watch` method from `vue` package and run it on your router? `watch(route.query)`, like in any composables?

Comment: No because I want to watch in my .js plugin file; not within a component.

Comment: [watch](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch) can watch any object. Did you try watching `this.$router.currentRoute` ?

Comment: I know, but *where* is `$watch` in my Vue instance (So not in my components)

Answer (score 1):

In Vue3, everything related to reactivity is out of any Vue instance. That means you can create a watcher without even having a Vue app:

```js
import { watch } from 'vue'

export function myPlugin(route) {
  watch(route.query, (newQuery, oldQuery) => {
    // TODO
  })
}
```

There is no more a global `$watch` property on Vue instances.